# how to find which user performed DML operations in a table in oracle?

Tags: oracle

how to find which user performed DML operations in a table in oracle? Need a query to find out from DB?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is auditing.

[Monitoring Database Activity with Auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dbseg/part_6.html)

Traditional auditing:

```
audit all on owner.mytable by access;
```

Unified auditing:

```
create audit policy mypolicy actions all on owner.mytable;
audit policy mypolicy;
```

If `audit_trail` is set to `DB` or `DB,EXTENDED`, results can be queried from [DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL.html#GUID-A9993FAC-12D3-4725-A37D-938CC32D74CC) in case of traditional auditing.
With Unified auditing, results can be queried from [UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL.html#GUID-B7CE1C02-2FD4-47D6-80AA-CF74A60CDD1D).